# Php Mysql multiple Selected Option

Tags: php, mysql

hello mysql table is as below.
1.) edit-reference?id=58
When I enter the page, there is an error in my select operation, reference_categories all selected.

2.) Another issue is when I want to post the form
In the table "ref_sel_categories"
reference_id: 58 has reference_category_id: 92 in both columns.

**table name 'reference'**

```
id:58
referencetitle :helloword 1
id:59
referencetitle :helloword 2
```

---

**table name 'reference_categories'**

```
category_id: 92
category_name: word category 1
category_id: 93
category_name: word category 2
category_id: 94
category_name: word category 3
category_id: 95
category_name: word category 4
category_id: 96
category_name: word category 5
```

---

**table 'ref_sel_categories'**

```
id:1
reference_id:58
reference_category_id:92
id:2
reference_id:58
reference_category_id:93
id:3 
reference_id:59
reference_category_id:94
id:4
reference_id:59
reference_category_id:94
id:5
reference_id:59
reference_category_id:94
```

```
$id = get('id');

$row = $db->from('reference')
    ->where('reference_id', $id)
    ->first();
    
    $categories = $db->from('reference_categories')
    ->orderby('category_name', 'ASC')
    ->all();
    
    $selectcategory = $db->from('ref_sel_categories')
    ->where('reference_id', $id)
    ->first();
    
    if (post('submit')) {
    $PostCategories = post('reference_categories');
    if (!isset($error)) {

                    foreach ($_POST[$PostCategories as $selectedOption)
                    {
                        $update = $db->update('ref_sel_categories')
                            ->where('reference_id', $id)
                            ->set([
                                'reference_category_id' => $selectedOption,
                            ]);
                    }
           }
    
}
require 'edit-reference';
```

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select class="form-control" name="reference_categories[]" multiple data-max-options="4">
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<option <?= ($_POST['reference_categories'] ? $_POST['reference_categories'] : $selectcategory['reference_category_id']) ? ' selected' : null ?>
value="<?= $category['category_id'] ?>"><?= $category['category_name'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<div class="card-footer ml-auto mr-auto">
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">UPDATE</button>
</div>
</form>
```

```
<?php print_r($selectcategory['reference_category_id']) ?>
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2fZQ.jpg)

Comment: Where are you using `print_r`?  You have two updates being performed, which one are you referring to?  Where do you define `$data`?  Where is your `<form>` and what is being posted to the server?  It looks like the code shown is including information unrelated to the problem, but doesn't include information related to the problem.  Can you provide a complete (but minimal) example and specify exactly what isn't working as expected?  For tips and information on asking a question, you are also encouraged to take a look at [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I edited right now?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. maybe it will help others.

```
$id = get('id');
$row = $db->from('reference')
->where('reference_id', $id)
->first();

$categories = $db->from('reference_categories')
->orderby('category_name', 'ASC')
->all();

$selectcategory = $db->from('ref_sel_categories')
->join('reference_categories', '%s.category_id  = %s.reference_category_id')
->where('reference_id', $id)
->all();

$CatSelId = [];
foreach ($selectcategory as $SelCat) {
$CatSelId[] = trim($SelCat['reference_category_id']);
}

if (!isset($error)) {

$update = $db->update('reference')
->where('reference_id', $id)
->set($data);

if ($update) {

$postID = $id;

// Check and Add Any Changes in Category
$PostCategories = array_map('trim', $PostCategories);
$PostCategories = array_filter($PostCategories);
if (count($PostCategories) > 0) {
foreach ($PostCategories as $SelCat) {

// Kayıtlı Kategori var mı kontrol et
$row = $db->from('ref_sel_categories')
->where('reference_id', $id)
->where('reference_category_id', $SelCat)
->first();

if (!$row) {
$tagInsert = $db->insert('ref_sel_categories')
->set([
'reference_id' => $postID,
'reference_category_id' => $SelCat
]);
$ReferenceID = $db->lastId();
}

}
}

// Check Removed Selections! and delete
$diffs = array_diff($CatSelId, $PostCategories);
if (count($diffs) > 0) {
foreach ($diffs as $diff) {
foreach ($selectcategory as $allCategory) {
if (trim($allCategory['reference_category_id']) == $diff) {
$db->delete('ref_sel_categories')
->where('id', $allCategory['id'])
->where('reference_id', $id)
->done();
}
}
}
}

} else {
$error = 'Error';
}
}
```

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select class="form-control" name="reference_categories[]" multiple data-max-options="4">
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<option <?= (post('reference_categories') ? post('reference_categories') : $CatSelId)
&& in_array($category['category_id'], (post('reference_categories') ? post('reference_categories') : $CatSelId)) ? 'selected' : null ?>
value="<?= $category['category_id'] ?>"><?= $category['category_name'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<div class="card-footer ml-auto mr-auto">
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">UPDATE</button>
</div>
</form>
```